# reloading the UITableview does not reload the image in cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hi i have a **UITableView** and i am using custom cell in it which includes an image. When i reload the **UITableView** it is reloading just ok but the the image is not removing i set this to image to nil too and tried removeFromSuperView too but no luck.

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identity];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identity DefaultsArray:defaultColAndSpacesDict];

    if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}

if([[dtaDictionary allKeys] count]!=0)
{
    [cell.contentView clearsContextBeforeDrawing];

    if([defaultsArray containsObject:@"Note"])
    {

        NSString *patNotes=[[currRow objectForKey:@"pat_notes"] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
        NSString *appNotes=[[currRow objectForKey:@"Notes"] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

        if((![patNotes isEqualToString:@""] && patNotes!=nil) || (![appNotes isEqualToString:@""] && appNotes!=nil))
        {
            [cell.Note setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notes-green.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [cell.Note setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notes-green.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
            [cell.Note addTarget:self action:@selector(showNote:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }
        else
        {
                cell.Note.imageView.image=nil;
        }
    }
```

I debugged the program and it is assigning nil to it. i tried removeFromSuperView of ImageView too. What could be the problem?

Note: Cell.Note is a UIButton

Comment: add break point at  if condition and check, sure that if condition always get true.

Comment: Try [cell.Note setBackgroundImage:nil];

Comment: iPatel i tried using break point it is assigning nil to it.

Comment: Suresh is correct, though it should be `[cell.Note setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal]` and the same for `UIControlStateHighlighted` - same as you did in the other half of that if statement. Because UIButtons control their own images, you don't want to directly modify the imageView - the button's own code will override your changes. I would recommend though just hiding and unhiding the button (ie `cell.Note.hidden = YES`) as that prevents it catching any input events as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning an image into the imageView in the first place within the if condition.

For instance :

```
   if((![patNotes isEqualToString:@""] && patNotes!=nil) || (![appNotes isEqualToString:@""] && appNotes!=nil))
    {

       cell.Note.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"notes-green.png"];
         //Rest of Code

    }

   else
    {
          cell.Note.ImageView.image=nil ;
    }
```

The above case will work perfectly as now you are assigning some image to imageView.

But in your case you are assigning image by calling your custom method setBackgroundImage:. In this case it gets assigned to some other view which is been used within setBackgroundImage: method .

So for that consider the code below :

```
   if((![patNotes isEqualToString:@""] && patNotes!=nil) || (![appNotes isEqualToString:@""] && appNotes!=nil))
    {
        [cell.Note setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notes-green.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       //Rest of Code
    }

     else
    {
        [cell.Note setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
```

Hope its Clear!!!

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, you have set background image to button for control state. If you want to change background image or clear image, you have to set again background imgae for button.

```
[cell.Note setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"changedImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[cell.Note setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"changedImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Otherwise set nil to background image or just hide if u need.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `[cell.Note setNeedsDisplay]`

Comment: Here he didn't draw anything..Then why do we call 'setNeedDisplay'?

Comment: You have to call it to force refresh of the imageView that is reused inside the cell

Comment: Why you have to force refresh ? While reload, it already refresh your button. then why we need to call it again?. According to your point, isn't it call while reload?

Comment: According to my experience reload is not forcing the refresh of the imageView display inside the cell. Maybe it has been changed on newer iOS version